# DokuWiki login page editing

Tags: php, dokuwiki

I'm interested in simplifying the dokuwiki login page so it displays without the page header and page footer. Because these appear dynamically I can't seem to figure out how to prevent them from displaying.

I'd like all subsequent pages to load with the header and footer. Only the login page should appear in simplified form.

Answer (score 1):

This would not work with Dokuwiki's own features. The login-page is simply a content, like any other content of Dokuwiki too, and so it is displayed in the content-area.
You would have to write an plugin for Dokuwiki, which intercept the parser/renderer-chain an displays only the login page you created. It's not trivial, tough.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the template you are using. If you are using the default 'dokuwiki' template, you can create [userstyles](https://www.dokuwiki.org/devel%3acss#user_styles) with the following CSS which will simply hide the header and the footer:

```
.mode_login #dokuwiki__header,
.mode_login #dokuwiki__pagetools,
.mode_login #dokuwiki__footer,
.mode_login .pageId,
.mode_login .docInfo {
    display: none;
}
.mode_login #dokuwiki__content {
    padding-top: 1em;
}
```

If you're not using the default template, you only need to make sure that `<?php echo tpl_classes(); ?>` is inside a `class=""` somewhere around most of the code in your template's `main.php`. When you do that, the class `mode_login` is added whenever you're on the login page.

The rest of the CSS might need to change as well depending on how your template is structured.